# Securing rest app (separate view and server) + social logins

Tags: rest, security, authentication, oauth, spring-security

I'm getting into the world of fullstack development and I'm trying to develop app which front is completely separated from backend (front is being served from node server and backend is java).

Now, the issue - how should I get about securing my app?
I'd like to have many fronts and many backend instances connected through load balancers and I'd like to keep all the state on client, so I can without any issue switch to another backend server and continue as nothing happened.

Currently I'm using OAuth2 tokens but I'm concerned about security and stealing the tokens, which are completely stored in cookie on user side. Also, The app (obviously) stores those tokens somewhere, so another instance of my backend app wouldn't accept the token. In best case scenario I can implement some mechanism that would automatically request a new one and in worst case I'd have to login again. I don't want that to happen.

Also, here I have a problem with social auth. Allright, I'm receiving token from Google on front, but giving it to backend and creating a user there is major pain, I have to write a lot of code manually to create such user and save it.

And again, I'm not certain about security level of this solution.

So the question is basically - currently, what is the best way to secure an app which should have completely separate front and backend, which would have no issue with switch backend server between requests?

Answer (score 0):

As regards tokens being stolen from the Client: you can't do anything about this. It is up to the client to protect themselves.  What I mean is, if you need a username and password to access a service, and the Client is infected with a key-logger, and a hacker steals those credentials, there is nothing you can do on the server side to protect against this.

As regards your idea of multiple back-ends, this is a common feature of any system with multiple application servers.  For example, if you have multiple web servers and want any request to be routable to any server. For this, you need a central database which stores any information which needs to be shared. It's slower, obviously, but much more resilient.